Network between Ubuntu(22.04) and macOs (14.5) over Thunderbolt
my first experience with IP over Thunderbolt comes from connecting two laptops with Ubuntu 22.04, usbc-usbc bridge. It was autoconfigured, I used at that time one program client-server to measure maximum network throughput (10Gbit as slower port on Lenovo T14, second one T470 has 40Gbit but negotiation was for what both can provide). Also some transfers over sftp, so everything was working.
Now I connected my mbPRO (A1990) with macOS 14.5 with Lenovo T14 (Ubuntu 22.04 used earlier) and what we have:

both computers configured interface (thunderbolt0 on Ubuntu, bridge0 on macOS) with 196.254.x.x addresses
I can ping from Mac to Ubuntu but with quite high time around 140ms
I cannot ping Mac's address from Ubuntu
I've set python -m http.server 8000 on Ubuntu, netstat shows its binded to all interfaces (0.0.0.0)
I can open on Ubuntu server on localhost and it works
I cannot open T14_IP:8000 server from Mac
nmap to T14_IP do not give any results
I set up http server on Python on Mac, it’s locally available but not from T14, some small window asked me if this connection should be available from external, I confirmed

What should I setup more to have full unrestricted connections in both directions?
